# What does the quote "Only a fool see fools" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotes

What does the quote "Only a fool see fools" mean?? I just can't actually grasp the idea....

Comment: That's not actually grammatical.

Comment: Lacks context. Lacks the name of the source. Lacks any attempt of research. Did you look up the word "fool" before asking your question? What did you find out?

Comment: I looked it up actually and found a possible complete quote by Marianne Butler. sorry! this is my first post. will provide more info next time.

Answer (score 2):

The only quote with that text I found was here: http://inspired.maryannebutler.com.au/?tag=wise-sayings

The full quote is:

> “Only a fool sees fools
>
> For a wise man sees
>
> Another man’s reason”
>
> -Maryanne Butler, 1987

Using that context, she is saying that if you are wise, you are able to see reason in other people --- and therefore do not see them as fools. I think her use of the word "reason" her refers to "the ability to think" and not to "a cause or explanation," but both interpretations lead to similar conclusions.

In contrast, if you see another human being as foolish, it implies that you are not wise enough to put yourself in their shoes, and thus are a fool yourself. (This gets a bit circular if you think about it too long, because judging people as foolish because they cannot understand other people shows a lack of understanding of the very people you are judging.)

It seems to me that the intent is to implore you to look for reason in others rather than assuming they are stupid.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seemed to make so much more sense now! I Googled everywhere and I saw what appears to be the complete quote by Maryanne Butler, but I am not even sure if she quoted from someone else or it was her quote... Thank you again for your help!